# Eating outside of a Sukkah - Negative or Positive commandment?

Tags: halacha-theory, mitzvah, sukkot, sukkah

On [Sukkoth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukkoth) we are required to dwell in a [Sukkah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukkah), which is generally minimally defined as at least eating our meals (which in turn is generally minimally defined as grain-based products) inside the Sukkah.  If one was outside of a Sukkah (whether outside unsheltered entirely or inside a building) and ate something that meets the minimum definition of a food that is required to be eaten inside a Sukkah, would that be an activity that falls under the category of a Lo Tha'aseh (prohibition), a Bittul 'Aseh (not actively fulfilling a positive commandment), or an Isur 'Aseh (prohibition due to falling outside the requirements of a positive commandment)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no lav in the Torah against eating outside the Sukkah, so it would just be a bitul aseh. It says "Basukkos teshvu", but does not say anythink like "lo tochal chutz me'suka".

Answer (score 13):

I don't have an explicit answer, but since [women are not obligated to sit in the sukkah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10535/should-women-eat-in-the-sukkah), and we know that women are obligated to fulfill negative commandments, it would stand to reason that eating out of the Sukkah would be a Bittul Asseh.