# Is there a practical difference between different types of Berachos?

Tags: halacha, blessing

Berachos tend to be grouped into different categories, as Berachos on pleasure (ברכות הנהנין), on Mitzvos (ברכות המצות), on events (ברכות ראיה ושמיעה), etc.

As far as I’m aware, the general halachos of these types of Berachos are the same across all categories; for instance, they all are said in response to certain triggers, whether that trigger is eating something, hearing some type of news, discharging an obligation, or something else.

Are there any halachos unique to one type of Beracha which don’t apply to the others?

Comment: Birkas Illanoys is said only on Nissan? Birkas Hagomel is said in Minyan? Some are said once in 30 days?

Comment: I don't think the Q reflects the title. And what Halochos you refer to?

Comment: @AlBerko Birchas Ilanos is a specific application of the general rule that Berachos are said in response to a prompt. Hagomel is indeed only said in a minyan, but that’s not a rule of general categories of Berachos; Hagomel would be a Birchas Hoda’ah, which generally do *not* have to be said in a minyan.

Comment: If so the question is undecipherable for me.

Comment: @AlBerko Why don’t you think the Q reflects the title? I’m asking for a practical difference between Beracha categories - do any categories have unique halachos? I’m referring to, I dunno, any Halacha which applies to a category as a whole. When it’s said (if there’s a category which can be said whenever whyever), how it’s said, etc. If I knew what specific Halacha was different, I wouldn’t be asking this question.

Comment: Birkos Hashachar are all different Halachicly I think.

Comment: @AlBerko How so?

Comment: Birkos Nehenin have measures etc. I'm lost, I don't understand - there are tons of Brochos including tens in Tefilla alone. Each one has its own aspects and nuances. Are you asking after reading Shu"A or before?

Comment: @AlBerko Some types of Berachos before, some after. Yes, each type of Beracha has a unique prompt, but every Beracha is said on some prompt AFAIK. What kind of halachos are unique to some Berachos but not others? Please post it as an answer, rather than a “your question doesn’t make sense.”

Comment: I showed you Birkos Hashachar are said without prompt, Amida's 19 Brochos are said without a trigger either etc.

Comment: In my view, the classification you make in #1 is later and artificial. Rabbis were free to propose any Brochos they wanted, eventually, they were standardized a bit but the Halochos are different one from another.

Comment: @AlBerko That’s not true - Birchos Hashachar are said on the rooster crowing, on getting out of bed, on putting on shoes, etc. The minhag Ashkenaz seems to be predominantly to say it in shul, but indeed, many Sefardim say it on those prompts immediately. Shemoneh Esrei is also said on a prompt - the Mitzvah of davening three times a day. What you reminded me, though, is that Tefillas Nedavah indeed is an exception to this rule.

Answer (score 5):

- The law that כל הברכות מברכין עובר לעשייתן - that one must bless
  before performing a *mitzva* - does not apply by *Birchas Hareach
  uReiyah* (and according to most opinions is unique to *Birchas
  HaMitzvos*; the reason *Birchas Hanehenin* must precede the
  consumption is because אסור להנות מעולם הזה בלא ברכה).
- According to some opinions, one must stand for *Birchas HaMitzvos*
  (see ארחות חיים (הל' ציצית סי' כז - כח), Rosh (Pesachim, Ch. 10 §41),
  Magen Avraham §8.2); we do not see this law by other Brachos.
- According to some Rishonim (although we may not *pasken* like that),
  the rule of ספק ברכות להקל (to avoid making *brachos* when in doubt)
  applies only to *Birchas HaMitzvos*, not other *brachos* (See Tosfos
  Brachos 12a, with Gilyon Hashas of R' Akiva Eiger).
- The law of *arvus* (אף על פי שיצא, מוציא) is primarily by *Birchas Hamitzvos*, not by the other categories of Brochos.

Comment: Notably, pretty much all these rules have exceptions. Categories are only as useful as their exceptions after all.

Comment: See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15018/berakhos-recited-over-food-mitzvah-or-matir/103602#103602 - *Birchas Hanehenin* may be a *mattir*; Birchas Hamitzvos are not. There are numerous ramifications.

Answer (score 2):

One difference is that berachas on events are said after the fact (We say the beracha on thunder after we hear the thunder, on lightning after the lightning, Hagomel after being saved, etc).

Berachas on mitzvos are almost always said before the fact-מברכים עובר לעשייתן (b’racha on hallel, Lulav, shofar, Megillah, etc).

And berachas on pleasure are said before and after the fact (b’racha rishonah, b’racha achrona etc).