# Loss of not making a bracha on a mitzva

Tags: blessing, mitzvah

[Berachot 35b:](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.35b.2?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi)

> Rabbi Ḥanina bar Pappa said: Anyone who derives benefit from this world without a blessing, it is as if he stole from God and the community of Israel

This is commonly applied to the case where one does not make a bracha on the food he eats or on the spices he smells, but can it also be applied to mitzvot? What downside is there to performing a mitzva without a bracha from the outset? Is it only a lack of the benefit of making a bracha? If so, please provide sources explaining the benefits of making a bracha on a mitzva

Comment: it could be a matir https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15027/759

Comment: I don't see how the question is pertinent. The gemara doesn't say that this rule covers the whole problem of the lack of bracha.

Comment: The downside is you didn't fulfill the Rabbinic injunction to make the required blessing.

Answer (score -1):

As "מצוות לאו ליהנות נתנו" - Mitzvot are not given for benefit - it seems this rule would not apply there.

Comment: This issue may not obtain here, but are there other issues? The OP was asking broadly.